# Boot CD ROM via floppy?

Tags: boot, compact-disc, floppy, boot-manager

I have an older computer (1994) and it can't boot from CDROM.  How can I install some sort of boot manager that lets me boot from any CD?

Comment: It's a computer that is unused. It's hard drive is currently blank.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here - [Bart's CD-Rom Boot Disk](http://www.nu2.nu/bootdisk/cdrom/). When I had a similar issue, I used this. You can generate a floppy disk that will contain the drivers needed to boot off of a CD drive.

In addition, unless this is for someone else, if it is a machine that you have an old application on, have you thought about virtualisation?

Answer (score 1):

[Smart boot manager](http://btmgr.sourceforge.net/about.html) might be of help